# No internet connection on host machine vmware workstation 14 Player

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, bridge

I'm trying to make 5 Windows XP virtual machines run simultaneously. We need these virtual machines in order to run a software which is incompatible with 64-bit operating systems. The virtualization software we're using is VMware Workstation 14 Player and the host system is Windows 7 Entreprise.

Each of these VM have to be connected to our internal network in order to access specific servers, that's why we've decided to use the network Bridge mode. When I try to run 3 virtual machines simultaneously, both the virtual machines and the host system have access to our internal network and work perfectly.

But whenever I try to run 4 virtual machines or more simultaneously, neither the virtual machines nor the host system have access to our internal network. When I close the 4th virtual machine (and any other additional virtual machine), after waiting for 3 or 4 minutes, our network connection is back.

Would you know if there is a setting that I have to add or change in VMware Workstation Player or if there's something else that I could do in order to fix this please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  You probably should report it on the VMware support forums.

Comment: VMware Player should only allow you to run one VM at a time, per it's specs.  (https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player.html) How are you able to run 4?  A better platform for this would be ESXi.  Also, be careful with licensing, running desktop OSes as remote VMS requires extra licensing from MS.

Comment: Understood, thank you essjae. About being able to run 4 VM, I'm surprised too

Comment: @essjae No, VMware Player allows you to run only one VM at a time *per VMware Player instance*.  There is nothing wrong with running multiple instances of VMware Player.  VMs run independently of each other in separate processes, so from the VMs' perspectives, there is no difference from VMware Player and VMware Workstation.  Certainly 4 VMs should not be an issue.  If running all 4 doesn't work but running *any combination* of 3 *does work*, then it sounds like a bug that should be reported.